# Programmatically send keystrokes to GLUT application

Tags: linux, opengl, automation, glut

I have an OpenGL/GLUT program running on my linux machine that views a 3D model from various angles and can take screenshots, and everything is controlled from the keyboard.  I want to write a script that moves around the model in a particular way, taking screenshots at every step.  It seems there should be a simple way in Linux to send keystrokes to this application from a script.  Anyone know how?

Comment: See this question/answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164460/programmatically-launching-standalone-adobe-flashplayer-on-linuxx11#165089

Answer (score 1):

Take the GLUT source-code and make it remote controllable. One way to do this is to remove the function that polls the keyboard and let it poll a socket instead. Link the program with the existing program with the new library.

Afterwards you can establish a connection to the now remote-controllable program and set key-codes programmatically from your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject events into an X11 window.  I think [xnee](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xnee.html) will do that for you.  I think that "inspect" (using a feature of Tk?) used to do this as well.